# Android debugger error (MonoDroid)

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm developping an Android app in Visual Studio 2010 with MonoDroid. 
I'm already pretty far and was able to run and debug my app on the emulator aswell as a Android device. For some reason my Visual Studio is not debugging the app properly to my device anymore. The error i (sometimes) get is:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

The application could not be started. Ensure that the application has been installed to the target device and has a launchable activity (MainLauncher = true).

### Additionally, check Build->Configuration Manager to ensure this project is set to Deploy for this configuration.

### OK

(ALL of the solutions above I've already checked..)

Other times there is no error at all and Visual Studio just stops running or the app starts fine but visual studio is non responsive.

The error just started recently while (almost) nothing has changed on the application. I was hoping someone had this error before and knew if it was because of some property setting or something?

PS: I also believe it could be caused by my camera, I use it in my app and when my app decides to deploy (~1 in 5 times) it crashed on the camera screen, here's the cameracode:

```
    private void CreateCamera(ISurfaceHolder holder)
    {
        try
        {
            if (holder != null)
            {
                camera = Android.Hardware.Camera.Open();
                Android.Hardware.Camera.Parameters p = camera.GetParameters();
                p.PictureFormat = ImageFormatType.Jpeg;
                camera.SetParameters(p);
                camera.SetDisplayOrientation(90);
                camera.SetPreviewCallback(this);
                camera.Lock();
                camera.SetPreviewDisplay(holder);
                camera.StartPreview();

                if (PackageManager.HasSystemFeature("android.hardware.camera.autofocus"))
                {
                    camera.AutoFocus(this);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            Android.Util.Log.Debug("SIMPLECAMERA", e.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i don't what caused these crazy errors but by one point my phone (HTC One X) was getting a bit buggy itself.. Because of that I resetted my phone (by holding the powerbutton) and that fixed all my problems.

Ps: Still a bit worried this was because of my application.. i.e. memory leakage or some other bad implementing error..

Comment: The first error is somehow related to visual studio unchecking the project from deploying to the device.  Happens to me, I'll have to check the configuration manager to make sure its deploying my project.

Answer (score 10):

In Visual Studio 2010: Build -> Configuration Manager -> Put a check in the "Deploy" box.

This happened to me when I changed from Debug configuration to Release. For some reason, the Deploy box remained unselected.

Answer (score 7):

For me, I had the Deploy checkbox ticked all along but **found the trick if you're targeting "Any CPU" for emulators is to explicitly target x86.**

I'm running a 32 bit PC and the x86 platform setting is in the Configuration Manager:

[image]

[image]

[image]

First time you run the app it takes a few minutes (to install platform framework and etc).

**Edit:** I just found the [official documentation](http://docs.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/configuring_the_x86_emulator/), some issue with ARM based architecture and x86 being the way to go

Comment: Thanks for saving me hours!!  This was the exact solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

**Specific to Android**

If at all you tried all the above solutions still not succeed, go to your Application Manager and check is there anything installed with your app name or service name and un-install the same.

Sometimes even you un-install also still app will show in Application Manager with 0KB in size.

It happened to me when I change from release mode to debug mode.

Comment: Could have said "check this first if Android and app contains a service". Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

I had to uninstall the application, Mono Shared Runtime and Xamarin.Android API which worked.